# Kafka in a Docker Container - External and and Internal connections

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a situation where, Kafka is running in a docker container using a specific IP address within a network. The network is created using the following command

```
sudo docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16  --gateway 172.19.0.1 --ip-range=172.19.0.1/24 my_net
```

Kafka container is started using the following

```
docker run -d --name kafkanode --net my_net --hostname=kafkahost01 kafka_zook:212-358 -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 tail -f /dev/null
```

I have producers within the same host from a different container.
Kafka's server.properties a simple configuration like the below works for a producer within the same host and from a different container.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafkahost01:9092
```

However, in our case, we will have producers who will also be sending messages from outside of that machine.

[image]

Unfortunately, i am not able to get connected from outside the docker host machine. Can someone please help me with the configuration?

We are using Kafka 2.12-2.6.0
Zookeeper -- 3.5.8

Server properties edited with the following values

```
 listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092 
 listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT 
 advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://kafkahost01:29092,EXTERNAL://10.20.30.40:9092 
 inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: Just add another listener for external access

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer and x4k3p thanks. getting the following error

INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=10.20.30.40:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('10.20.30.40', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
Traceback (most recent call last):
      producer.send(b'tweets',value=kafka_data)
  File "C:kafka.py", line 576, in send
    self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
  File "C:kafka.py", line 702, in _wait_on_metadata
    raise Errors.KafkaTimeoutError(kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.

Comment: server.properties has the following configuration  
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
   listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
 advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://kafkahost01:29092,EXTERNAL://10.20.30.40:9092
   inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL

Comment: Please edit the post with additional information, but your listed IP and port seem fine, so now check firewall rules and use netcat to check the port from the external machine

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am able to get connected from another machine through kafkacat

kafkacat -b 10.20.30.40:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 0: 144.25.103.235:9092/0):
 1 brokers:
  broker 0 at 10.20.30.40:9092
 2 topics:
  topic "tweets" with 1 partitions:

    Further i tested with nc -vz 10.20.30.40 9092 from a differet machine. 
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.20.30.40:9092.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.

Not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: This address is different.  `from broker 0: 144.25.103.235:9092` Netcat to that

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a docker-compose example with inside and outside listeners configured. Try out.
*(Replace localhost with your desired IP or DNS)*

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.5.8
    hostname: zookeeper
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/data
      - zookeeper-datalog:/datalog

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.6.0
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - kafka:/kafka


volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
  zookeeper-datalog:
  kafka:
```

Running a producer within the same network:

```
# note: I just placed my docker-compose.yml in example dir, thats the reason for the example_default network
$ docker run -it --rm \
--name producer \
--network example_default \
wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.6.0 bash
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic 
example
>some
>test
```

And consuming from outside docker using [kaf](https://github.com/birdayz/kaf):

```
$ cat ~/.kaf/config
current-cluster: single
clusteroverride: ""
clusters:
- name: single
  version: 2.7.0
  brokers:
  - localhost:9093
  SASL: null
  TLS: null
  security-protocol: PLAINTEXT
  schema-registry-url: ""
$ kaf nodes
ID    ADDRESS          
1     localhost:9093
$ kaf consume example -f --raw 
some
test
```

Hope this example can help you define your own setup.

Comment: You should remove the advertised hostname and port settings since they're not used if advertised listeners are defined. This also doesn't address the issue with connecting from another machine

Comment: Thx, removed these envs. I already wrote in the first part that localhost should be replaced with IP/DNS to be able to connect from another machine. I use mostly the same setup „parts“ without issues (and connect remotely).

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am doing the deployment to azure container instance where ip address would be assigned at runtime. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: @Shail Please create a new post